# How to scale arrows?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I tried to scale the arrows. In the first graph, the white arrow is significantly wider than the gray ones. In the second graph, they look similar. But the ratio of the parameters are the same. How should I adjust it? Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows} 



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=4,yscale=4]

\draw [fill=white] (0,-0.8) circle [radius=0.1];



 \node[draw, single arrow,
          minimum height=20mm, minimum width=12mm,
          single arrow head extend=2mm,
          anchor=west, rotate=-90] at (0,-1) {};
          
\node[draw, single arrow,
          minimum height=23mm, minimum width=4mm,
          single arrow head extend=2mm,
          anchor=west, rotate=-125, fill=gray] at (-0.3,-1) {};
          
\node[draw, single arrow,
          minimum height=23mm, minimum width=4mm,
          single arrow head extend=2mm,
          anchor=west, rotate=-55, fill=gray] at (0.3,-1) {};
          
\draw (-0.1,-1.6) rectangle (0.1,-1.8);

\draw (-0.8,-1.6) rectangle (-0.6,-1.8);

\draw (0.6,-1.6) rectangle (0.8,-1.8);


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{figure}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{B}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2,yscale=2]

\draw [fill=white] (0,-0.8) circle [radius=0.1];



 \node[draw, single arrow,
          minimum height=10mm, minimum width=6mm,
          single arrow head extend=1mm,
          anchor=west, rotate=-90] at (0,-1) {};
          
\node[draw, single arrow,
          minimum height=11.5mm, minimum width=2mm,
          single arrow head extend=1mm,
          anchor=west, rotate=-125, fill=gray] at (-0.3,-1) {};
          
\node[draw, single arrow,
          minimum height=11.5mm, minimum width=2mm,
          single arrow head extend=1mm,
          anchor=west, rotate=-55, fill=gray] at (0.3,-1) {};
          
\draw (-0.1,-1.6) rectangle (0.1,-1.8);

\draw (-0.8,-1.6) rectangle (-0.6,-1.8);

\draw (0.6,-1.6) rectangle (0.8,-1.8);


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{figure}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it what You need?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows} 



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=4,yscale=4]

\draw [fill=white] (0,-0.8) circle [radius=0.1];



 \node[draw, single arrow,scale=0.2,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          minimum height=20mm, minimum width=12mm,
          single arrow head extend=2mm,
          anchor=west, rotate=-90] at (0,-1) {};
          
\node[draw, single arrow,scale=0.5,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          minimum height=23mm, minimum width=4mm,
          single arrow head extend=2mm,
          anchor=west, rotate=-125, fill=gray] at (-0.3,-1) {};
          
\node[draw, single arrow,scale=0.9,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          minimum height=23mm, minimum width=4mm,
          single arrow head extend=2mm,
          anchor=west, rotate=-55, fill=gray] at (0.3,-1) {};
          
\draw (-0.1,-1.6) rectangle (0.1,-1.8);

\draw (-0.8,-1.6) rectangle (-0.6,-1.8);

\draw (0.6,-1.6) rectangle (0.8,-1.8);


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```